# Expand / Shrink Table Cell Text On Window Resizing

Tags: html, css

I have table rows of 2 cells. In left cells, there are long text values.

I would like to dynamically expand or shrink left cells text on window resizing. Left table cells should have `max-width` after which text in it should stay intact. And if the text is too long it should have `...` ellipsis at the end of it.

At the same time, right table cells should have a fixed width, since it contains regular text with predictable width.

Below is an example of handling this with containers:

```css
#wrapper {
  max-width: 400px;
}
#leftCell {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#rightCell {
    float:right;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<span id="rightCell">Fixed size cell</span>  
<span id="leftCell">This cell should be expandable by ellipsis</span>
</div>
```

Comment: you have tried something on your own?

Comment: @NoobEditor I did. But wasn't able to find workable solution yet.

Comment: Whoever down-voted the question should keep in mind, that the right answer helps better for a community than an accidental click :)

Comment: post the code you have tried so far... in your words, community works better with a code example than making vague guesses! :)

Comment: Yes appreciated but this community not for suggestion this one for help while stuck in their code.at least try to explain with your minimal tries.

Comment: You are right guys. Added code snippet. All down-voters should be happy now and try to help with answering the question.

Comment: `And if the text is too long it should have ...`, you want to get the text width in run time - dynamic manner ?  using css?

Answer (score -2):

You can use [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) to achieve this;

```
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi quis dui ut odio tincidunt semper quis fermentum ligula. Donec pretium ac purus vitae efficitur. Nulla vitae ipsum semper, aliquet odio vitae, volutpat nisi. Curabitur efficitur ac lorem quis pharetra. Sed sit amet massa nulla.</div>

.text { max-width: 300px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; }
```